# How do I delete occurences from my List<T> with a bunch of Tuples inside?

Tags: c#, list

```
List<(int, int)> VotedTeam = new List<(int, int)>
{
    (1, 3),
    (1, 3),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1),
};
```

Just to give a contextualization of my problem.

I have a List of Tuples, the List represents a Team of players, and each tuple the player by itself.

The first number is its identification number and the second one is its given votes (the number of votes that it receives as being known as the best player of the match).

I tried some methods to delete duplicate players but didn't work.

Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: I'd suggest making a `Player` class and having a list of `Player` rather than a list of tuples.

Comment: Walk the list using `foreach`, figuring out the indexes you want to remove.  Then remove items from the list (but make sure to do that from the largest index back to the smallest)

Comment: `(1, 3)` is a `(int, int)` tuple thus the code does not compile: do you want `List<Tuple<int, int>>` ? Or even the HasSet suggested by @AndrewSilver. Also no need to specify the Tuple class since C# 7.

Comment: Please post valid code in the future. I've fixed it now though. Please check that I've got it right.

Comment: Agreeing with a class would be nicer than a tuple, to be prepared for future additions and although thinking that a `Distinct` as in the answer below is a good quick fix, I can not help but think the problem can be prevented by the way the list is created in the first place. It seems that for each vote the player is added anew. Perhaps the question should be how the duplicates arise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0), this collection can only contain unique elements and that will solve you problem automatically.
Like this:

```
var votedTeam = new HashSet<(int, int)> { (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index you can use votedTem.RemoveAt(index);

Answer (score 0):

Given this code:

```
List<(int, int)> VotedTeam = new List<(int, int)>
{
    (1, 3),
    (1, 3),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1),
};
```

This worked for me:

```
VotedTeam = VotedTeam.Distinct().ToList();
```

It gave me:

```
    (1, 3)
    (2, 2)
    (3, 1)
```